# PIE.htc is not working

Tags: xhtml, web.xml, css3pie

I have mapped the mimi type in web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
<extension>htc</extension>
<mime-type>text/x-component</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**My xhtml file resides in** `WebContent/tasks/task/include/test.xhtml`

**My css file resides in** `WebContent/css/test.css`

**My PIE.htc file resides in** `WebContent/pie/PIE.htc`

**In my CSS, I have the rule:**

```
    .test{
       border-radius:5px;
       position:relative;
       zoom:1;
       behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
    }
```

But IE8 is not displaying rounded corners. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it show round corner in IE7? Did you try the Developer extension (F12) and see if the PIE.htc is properly loaded. Is the PIE.htc version covering IE8 (there are old version not supporting IE8 well)

Comment: I tried over a flat directory structure on IIS and it works on IE8. How do I check if PIE.htc is being properly loaded using IE developer extension?

Comment: Developer tools is part of IE8 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then go to the tab that shows the list of loaded files. if PIE.htc shows properly then it's not a loading issue

Comment: Where is the tab that shows the list of loaded files? I just see the following tabs - html, css, script and profiler.

Comment: I selected the element, went to the style rule that has 'behavior:url()' and played around with the url. Still doesn't work...does that mean the .htc file is not being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I fixed it. I added the full url such as *http://www.test.com/* and also tried *../*

```
.test{
   border-radius:5px;
   position:relative;
   z-index:0;
   behavior: url(http://www.test.com/tasks/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

**OR**

```
.test{
   border-radius:5px;
   position:relative;
   z-index:0;
   behavior: url(../../../pie/PIE.htc);
}
```